# Mobile Responsive CSS - Not Centered on iPhone

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a mobile responsive site. On the site on a laptop, it looks great and all cards/navbars etc are centered.

But on my phone everything is not centered. Everything starts more to the left. It looks centered at first and then if you scroll over to the right there is some of the background image still over there.
The cards are shifted slightly to the right also - not centered.

But again this only happens on the phone. I was in Safari on my iphone.

Any suggestions?

My html has this in the header:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

css:

```
body {

    background-image: url('../../static/capstone/island.jpeg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #FFFAFA;
    }

.navbar1 {

grid-auto-flow: column;
position: relative;
min-height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
opacity: 0.75;
padding-top: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
transition: 0.4s; 
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin-top: 120px;
  position: relative;

 -ms-flex-pack:justify;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  transition: 0.4s; 
 }

.navbar > .container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
 }


  .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.75;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em;

  }

 .card {
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  transition: 0.4s;
 }

  .nav_text {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  }

 .card .card_title {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  height: 40px;
 }

  .card_text {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 30px;
  }



 .title-black {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
 }


.form-control {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
width: 83%;
margin:0 auto;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
outline: transparent;
border: transparent;
padding: 7%;
display: flex;
border-radius: 15px;
margin: 0.25rem;
padding: 1.5rem;
font-size: 20px;
box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(195, 193, 198, 0.9),
-0.2rem -0.2rem 0.4rem #f0f2f5;
}


.submit {
border-radius: 12%;
color: Black;
box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(195, 193, 198, 0.9),
-0.2rem -0.2rem 0.4rem #f0f2f5;
width: 100px;
height: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
}





@media all and (max-width: 100%) {

.card-list {
flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried access it on mobile google crome? see if its centered there, because safari has different css value for mobilize

Comment: We really need the entire code for the page, all the HTML and CSS, in order to properly help you. If it's published on the web, you could provide us with a link. Or even better use CodePen to illustrate your problem. https://codepen.io

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this bit of code

```
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-padding-start: 0;
```

I posted it here because its to long to comment out

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below instead of your current codes and replace it

body {

```
    background-image: url('../../static/capstone/island.jpeg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #FFFAFA;
    }

.navbar1 {

grid-auto-flow: column;
position: relative;
min-height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
opacity: 0.75;
padding-top: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
-webkit-transition: 0.4s;
-o-transition: 0.4s;
transition: 0.4s; 
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.75;
  margin-top: 120px;
  position: relative;

 -ms-flex-pack:justify;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s; 
 }

.navbar > .container {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
 }


  .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.75;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 1em;

  }

 .card {
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
          box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
 }

  .nav_text {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
      flex-basis: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  }

 .card .card_title {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  height: 40px;
 }

  .card_text {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
      -ms-flex-direction:column;
          flex-direction:column;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 30px;
  }



 .title-black {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
 }


.form-control {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
width: 83%;
margin:0 auto;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
text-align: center;
outline: transparent;
border: transparent;
padding: 7%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
border-radius: 15px;
margin: 0.25rem;
padding: 1.5rem;
font-size: 20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(195, 193, 198, 0.9),
-0.2rem -0.2rem 0.4rem #f0f2f5;
        box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(195, 193, 198, 0.9),
-0.2rem -0.2rem 0.4rem #f0f2f5;
}


.submit {
border-radius: 12%;
color: Black;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(195, 193, 198, 0.9),
-0.2rem -0.2rem 0.4rem #f0f2f5;
        box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.3rem 0.5rem rgba(195, 193, 198, 0.9),
-0.2rem -0.2rem 0.4rem #f0f2f5;
width: 100px;
height: 25px;
cursor: pointer;
}





@media all and (max-width: 100%) {

.card-list {
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
}
}
```

Comment: Why he should try this code? Please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped - I figured out that I was using width in some cards and other items, and it was too large. So when I changed it to max-width: 345px; or anything smaller, everything started to fit much better and was easier to work with.